# Javascript - TypeError: listener must be a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, listener, eventemitter

Yet another 'listener must be a function' error.
I double checked all my parameters, checked for correct  syntax etc but still can't find where the problem is:

Here are my snippets of code.

in login.js:

```
global.eventEmitter = require('./helpers/EventEmitter.js');
var packetSwitch = require('./handlers/PacketSwitch.js');
global.ackHandler = require('./handlers/ACKPacketHandler.js');
...
global.eventEmitter.createAndFireEvent('opCodeReceived',packetSwitch.switch(opcode, decrypted, sock));
```

in PacketSwitch.js:

```
var packetHandler = require('./PacketHandler.js');
exports.switch = function(opcode, data, sock) {
    switch (opcode) {
        case 1:
            eventEmitter.createAndFireEvent('reqLoginReceived', packetHandler.handleLoginReq(data, sock));
            break;
        case 2:
            eventEmitter.createAndFireEvent('reqDateReceived', packetHandler.handleDateReq(data, sock));
            break;
        default:
            eventEmitter.createAndFireEvent('unknownReceived', packetHandler.handleUnknown(data, sock));
    }
};
```

let's suppose it enters case 2:
in PacketHandler.js:

```
exports.handleDateReq = function(data, sock) {
    global.eventEmitter.createAndFireEvent('handleDateAck', global.ackHandler.handleDateAck(sock));
};
```

in ACKPacketHandler.js:

```
exports.handleDateAck = function(sock) {
    sock.write("Test!");
};
```

in EventEmitter.js:

```
var eventEmitter = require('events');
const myEmitter = new eventEmitter.EventEmitter();

exports.createAndFireEvent = function(event, callback) {
    myEmitter.on(event, callback);
    myEmitter.emit(event);
};
```

And here's a screenshot of the error I get:
https://gyazo.com/6047c5917f937aa33f29f9fc40cdf5f7

Comment: whats on events.js line 130?

Comment: events.js line 130 isn't part of my code, but it's the default module of Node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your packet handler functions (e.g. `handleDateAck()`) are not *returning* functions. In fact, they don't seem to be returning anything. The return value is what you're currently using as the listener function passed to `emitter.on()`.

Comment: Also `handleLoginReq()`.

Comment: so I should add something like "return function() {..}"?

Comment: Either that or restructure your logic to provide the callback in a different way, depending on your needs of course.

Comment: Solved by putting the logic into the
return function() {
  logic
}
bracket ^^

Thanks a lot!